# Wait for the end of a function to set state with UnderscoreJS under React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, underscore.js

I want to do a fetch then update the **markers** state. The problem is the state is updating before my fetch ends (due to asynchronous I think). I think there would be a solution with UnderscoreJS using the _.after function to set the state after my fetch ends. I don't know how to do that. Any idea?

Here my code:

```
onRegionChange(region) {

  let latitude = region.latitude;
  let longitude = region.longitude;

  let markers = [];

  _.filter(this.props.stations, (v) => 
    {
      if (this.getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(latitude,longitude,v.position.lat,v.position.lng) < 1) {

        fetch('https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations/' + v.number + '?contract=Paris&apiKey=3a9169028401f05f02bcffd87f4a3963dcd52f63')
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((station) => {
            console.log("station", station);
            markers.push({
              number: station.number,
              coordinate: {
                latitude: station.position.lat,
                longitude: station.position.lng
              },
              title: station.name,
              description: station.address,
              banking: station.banking,
              bonus: station.bonus,
              status: station.status,
              bike_stands: station.bike_stands,
              available_bike_stands: station.available_bike_stands,
              available_bikes: station.available_bikes,
              last_update: station.last_update
            });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.warn(error);
          });

      }

    }

  )

  this.setState({
    markers: markers
  })

  console.log("markers", this.state.markers);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mixing synchronous and asynchronous ideas and they don't mix well.

You're better off converting the synchronous values into promises (same thing the `fetch` is doing).

First I break out the drivel parts into functions. This cleans up the actual code and lowers the complexity.

```
function stationFetchUrl(station) {
  return `https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations/${station.number}?contract=Paris&apiKey=3a9169028401f05f02bcffd87f4a3963dcd52f63`;
}

function convertStationData(station) {
  return {
    number: station.number,
    coordinate: {
      latitude: station.position.lat,
      longitude: station.position.lng
    },
    title: station.name,
    description: station.address,
    banking: station.banking,
    bonus: station.bonus,
    status: station.status,
    bike_stands: station.bike_stands,
    available_bike_stands: station.available_bike_stands,
    available_bikes: station.available_bikes,
    last_update: station.last_update
  };
}

function stationNearRegion(region, station) {
  const distance = this.getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(
    region.latitude,
    region.longitude,
    stationStub.position.lat,
    stationStub.position.lng
  );
  return (distance < 1);
}
```

Next in the event handler I **map** over the stations and convert them to either `null` (in the case of the distance being `>= 1`) or fetch the new station data from the server (`fetch()`).

This results in an array of either promises or nulls. I use Underscore's `.compact()` to remove the null (same as filter did). Then I have an array of promises which I pass to `Promise.all` which waits till all the promises in the array resolve. When they do it passes the result of those promises (as an Array) to the `.then()` function which I dutifully use `this.setState()` on.

```
onRegionChange(region) {
  const markerPromises = _.chain(this.props.stations)
    .map(stationStub => {
      if (stationNearRegion.call(this, region, stationStub) {
        return fetch(stationFetchUrl(station))
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(convertStationData);
      }
    })
    .compact()
    .value();

  Promise.all(markerPromises)
    .then(markers => this.setState({markers}))
    .catch(error => console.log(error.toString()));
});
```

Since the `onRegionChange` is an event handler it would not return a promise. Instead we handle a possible error(s) by logging them in the `.catch()` block.

#### References

- [Chaining in Underscore.js](http://miniarray.com/chaining-in-underscore-js/) *(miniarray.com)*
- [Promise - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) *(developer.mozilla.org)*
- [You're Missing the Point of Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/) *(blog.domenic.me)*

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see what you mean. Could you explain please?

Comment: Thank you Sukima, but I'm sorry your code isn't working. I had to changed few things but it didn't work anymore, it return a null array.

Comment: @xavier-c I just fixed some typos. I'm don't editing now. Try again.

Comment: Ok your method is working great. The problem is now I need to understand it! ;) Thanks a lot Sukima for the time you spent on this problem.

Comment: @xavier-c I added some reference links that might help out.

Comment: @xavier-c Also cleaned up the code to make it clearer.